# Estimate on complex path integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I came across the question in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3891119/computing-integral-of-fz/3891122#3891122), where I wrote a partial answer. The question is to show that, for some constant $k>0$, we have
$$
\left|\int_{[-1,i]}(1+z+z^2+z^3)^n dz\right| \leq  k \left(\frac{4}{3 \sqrt{3}} \right)^n.
$$

What I did:

We can easily  compute the integral up to a certain point, obtaining
\begin{align*}
\int_{[-1,i]} (1+z+z^2+z^3)^n dz= &\int_{[-1,i]}(1+z)^n(1+z^2)^n \\
= & \int_0^1 (1+i) (t(1+i)^n)(2(1-t)-2t(1-t)i)^ndt\\
=& (1+i)^{n+1} 2^n \int_0^1 t^n(1-t)^n(1-ti)^n dt
\end{align*}

and so,
$$
\left| \int_{[-1,i]} f(z)^n dz \right|\leq \sqrt{2} (2\sqrt{2})^n \int_0^1 t^n (1-t)^n \left(\sqrt{1+t^2}\right)^n dt
$$

Although it is true that this upper bound is smaller than $\left(\frac{4}{3 \sqrt{3}}\right)^n$, and the result follows with $k=1$, I feel that there must be some simpler approach and would appreciate some ideas. In particular, nothing in my calculations gave any hint on the origin or motivation for the ratio $\frac{4}{3 \sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: The integral gives complex values. Maybe you meant $$
\int\limits_{[ - 1,i]} {\left| {1 + z + z^2  + z^3 } \right|^n dz} $$

Comment: @Raffaele It is something like that... I'll correct the post.

Comment: @Raffaele: The integral with absolute value would depend on the path of integration, which would break the claimed estimate. (The thing that's worth fixing is to take the absolute value of the integral, as done already ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has much to do with saddle points of $|f(z)|$ where $f(z)=1+z+z^2+z^3$.

Namely, the solutions of $f'(z)=0$ are $z=(-1\pm i\sqrt2)/3$, with $$f(z)=\frac{20\pm4i\sqrt2}{27},\quad|f(z)|=\color{blue}{\frac{4}{3\sqrt3}}.$$ Observe also that $f(-1)=f(i)=0$, so that we can choose a path $\gamma$ of integration from $-1$ to $i$, passing through $(-1+i\sqrt2)/3$, and such that $|f(z)|\leqslant 4/(3\sqrt3)$ for $z\in\gamma$ (apart from "general theory", it is actually easy to construct $\gamma$ explicitly).

This gives the desired estimate $\left|\int_\gamma f(z)^n\,dz\right|\leqslant\left(\frac{4}{3\sqrt3}\right)^n\int_\gamma|dz|$ immediately.

Comment: Thank you @metamorphy, this was exactly the king of simplicity I was looking for.